# How to resize images and appropriate xml files accordingly?

Tags: xml, image, object-detection

I am trying to apply object detection model to dataset that includes about 180 images and same number of xml files with bounding boxes coordinates for each image.
The problem is that all the images are of different size, but before putting them into the model they all should be of same size. If I just resize images all coordinates of bounding boxes will become incorrect so they should be updated too.

One solution is to resize images and them manually update each xml file, but would be good to have some other solution.

Comment: You don't need to resize the images, when creating tfrecord for training, all coordinates are transformed into relative coordinates (between 0 and 1) and all input images during training will be automatically resized.

Answer (score 0):

To resize your bounding box coordinates, you can use the following logic:
If your original image dimensions are (width_orig,height_orig),your resized image dimensions are (width_new,height_new) and your initial bounding box coordinates are `x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max`, your new bounding box coordinates will be `x_min*x_scale,y_min*y_scale,x_max*x_scale,y_max*y_scale` where `x_scale = width_new/width_orig`
`y_scale = height_new/height_orig`
Hopefully, if you finally need your annotations in csv format, you can use this [xml_to_csv](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/blob/master/xml_to_csv.py) converter to convert your xml files to csv and then read and modify the rows in csv file appropriately.

Hope this helps!